# Collecting links using Selenium results in StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been searching around Stackoverflow for a while now trying to find a fix for my specific use case as I keep getting StaleElementReferenceException from time to time (not all the time) but nothing I find seems to work.

I am trying to scrape a page and collect all links in the page.

```
driver.get(SOME_URL)
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for link in links:
      href = link.get_attribute('href')
      ... DO_SOMETHING_WITH_HREF ...
```

I've tried using implicit waits and tried to let my script sleep for a few seconds but both do not work. I've also been looking at explicit waits but fat as I know these are not possible as a link might occur anywhere on the page. Making it so there is no specific element I van wait for.

Comment: Collect all the href values and then use them. links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]. Then loops links to use. You might be going to another page and your element links will become stale.

Answer (score 0):

StaleElementReferenceException means the DOM has changed on which the function was called. Since you did something with the links, you can't loop through the rest. My advice is storing them in a list:

```
links.append(href)
```

and at the end you loop through this list. This because you do not interact with the elements and do not get the error message.